# wso2mb: error with durable subscriber

Tags: jms, wso2, esb, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2MB version 2.1.1.

I have two ESB processes that have subscribed to a topic queue using a durable subscription.

Now, the processes have been redeployed and they cannot listen to the topic anymore.

**In the ESB log I see:**

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-06-16 12:07:14,364]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection} -  Unable to connect to broker at tcp://localhost:5822 {org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection}
org.wso2.andes.AMQTimeoutException: Server did not respond in a timely fashion [error code 408: Request Timeout]
```

**In the MB log I see:**

```
  TID: [0] [MB] [2015-06-16 12:02:39,015]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.protocol.AMQProtocolEngine} -  Cannot subscribe to queue clientID:NewCaseUpdateLocation as it already has an existing exclusive consumer whilst processing:[BasicConsumeBodyImpl: ticket=0, 
queue=clientID:NewCaseUpdateLocation, consumerTag=1, noLocal=false, noAck=false, exclusive=true, nowait=false, arguments=null] 
{org.wso2.andes.server.protocol.AMQProtocolEngine}
```

How can I re-register this subscription, or force-remove the old one?

In MB I have no way to unregister since the registration was done from ESB.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be because the previous durable subscription was not deactivated properly (similar issue is reported [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4295) )hence when redeploying MB will not allow to have the same durable subscription ID for two subscribers unless it is a [shared subscription](https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB300/Managing+Durable+Topic+Subscriptions#ManagingDurableTopicSubscriptions-Sharingadurabletopicsubscription).

On a side note from MB 3.1.0 on wards you can close active durable subscribers from the MB console.